# How to scan a text file and extract data from it according to a search criteria in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I’m trying to create a webpage that includes a calendar (query datepicker) to play a video for a particular day stored on vimeo .
So far I managed to get the date on which I clicked assigned to a var (date).
Now I need to find the corresponding vimeo ID to this date in order to assign it to the embedded vimeo player.
I thought that the best way to do this is to read a text file with below content that I have stored in my webpage folder.

……

02-04-2014_Vevey 98230271 
              02-05-2014_Vevey 98231062 
              02-06-2014_Vevey 98231771 
              03-04-2014_Vevey 98232437 
              03-05-2014_Vevey 98232658 
              03-06-2014_Vevey 98233405 
              04-04-2014_Vevey 98234165 
            04-05-2014_Vevey 98234754

....

each line containing a date information with corresponding vimeo ID.

The point is that I am just beginning with Javascript and don’t know how to send a search criteria, read a file line by line, extract the date from first part, compare it with the search criteria and then return the ID.
Is there anyone willing to take some time for helping me?
Thank you.

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Here ([**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/yubexada/3/edit?js,console)):

```
// Simulating your datasource.
var data = "\
02-04-2014_Vevey 98230271\n\
02-05-2014_Vevey 98231062\n\
02-06-2014_Vevey 98231771\n\
03-04-2014_Vevey 98232437\n\
03-05-2014_Vevey 98232658\n\
03-06-2014_Vevey 98233405\n\
04-04-2014_Vevey 98234165\n\
04-05-2014_Vevey 98234754";
// Have your data as an array, split by line break
data = data.split('\n');

function search(from, to) {
  from = normalize(from);
  to = normalize(to);

  function normalize(date) {
    return '' +
      date.getFullYear() +
      zeroPad2(date.getMonth()+1) +
      zeroPad2(date.getDate());
  }

  function zeroPad2(number) {
    return ('00'+number).slice(-2);
  }

  // do the actual filtering
  return data.filter(function (name) {
    var date = name.match(/^(\d{2})\-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/);
    date = parseInt(date[3]+date[1]+date[2], 10);
    return (date <= to) && (date >= from);
  });

}

// Keep in mind that months are zero-based.
var from = new Date(2014, 02, 04); // 03-04-2014
var to = new Date(2014, 03, 06); // 04-06-2014
var searchResult = search(from, to);
console.log(searchResult);
```

Comment: Looks great gtramontina but I need sometime, fist to understand and then to test. Could you please help me further in putting this in a html file? I see that you wrote "simulating data source"; does it mean I could read it in from a file?; because this is what it is; i.e. I have a file that is automatically generated (completed) every day from a bash script.

Comment: Are you going to host this somewhere – http:// –, or this is a plain html file you'll access from file://? If it is going to be hosted, then I suggest your server to provide a resource `/videos` to which you'll issue requests like: `GET /videos?from=03-04-2014&to=04-06-2014`. Then the whole job of reading the file and searching lives on the server rather than the client.

Comment: my website is hosted at home on the same machine that creates said file. At the moment it is written by a bash script into the same folder as my 'index.html' file. But i can put it wherever needed. Can also reformat the content, but just need a date and a text reference. For example: 03-06-2014_Camera1 xyzxyz where xyzxyz corresponds to a reference I need to get a vimeo video played. See also above reply to Julien

Answer (score 0):

You can request the full content of your file by doing an httpXMLrequest on its path (or $.ajax if you use jquery), then you can process it with some regex.

However, it will be much easier if you store your data with an organized format like xml.

With an xml file you will be able to query it with xpath, which makes it very easy to find what you are looking for in your file.

here is the exact code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function vimeo_id_search() {
  var message = document.evaluate("//VimeoIds//VimeoID[@date='04-04-2014']",document.documentElement, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML += message.snapshotItem(0).getAttribute("id");
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<VimeoIds>
    <VimeoID date="02-04-2014" id="Vevey 98324123">
    <VimeoID date="03-04-2014" id="Vevey 23565723">
    <VimeoID date="04-04-2014" id="Vevey 67578673">
    <VimeoID date="05-04-2014" id="Vevey 09876542">
</VimeoIDs>

<button onclick="vimeo_id_search()">Try it</button>
<div id="info" style="background-color:#e0b0b0; width:400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe I got the idea, but my limited skills do not even allow me to have my test script running (see new  post)

Answer (score 0):

@ Julien; tried your proposed solution, but seems obviously to be wrong (see below).
One more thing is that the "date-ID" data is stored in an external file wich is updated every day via a bash script (automated timelapse movie generator). So I somehow need to get this data into the page.....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function vimeo_id_search() {
  var message = document.evaluate("//VimeoIds//VimeoID//@date[04-04-2014]",document.documentElement, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = message;
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<VimeoIds>
    <VimeoID date="02-04-2014" id="Vevey 98324123">
    <VimeoID date="03-04-2014" id="Vevey 23565723">
    <VimeoID date="04-04-2014" id="Vevey 67578673">
    <VimeoID date="05-04-2014" id="Vevey 09876542">
</VimeoIDs>

<button onclick="vimeo_id_search()">Try it</button>
<div id="info" style="background-color:#e0b0b0; width:400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And do you have a way to configure the output of this batch or do you have to stick with this format <DATE>_Vevey <ID> ?

Can you tell us more about the constraints or freedom you have with this generated file ?

Comment: No constraint at all. Just need a date and a text reference. This file is automatically generated every night after sundown via a bash script when uploading a video created with ffmpeg from 1500 pictures taken during the day. The text reference allows me to know from which camera are the pictures that were used for the timelapse video. you can see an uploaded example here https://vimeo.com/98247924, and what I try to do here www.oryxcam.com